# To add vs to be added

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Friends,

what exactly is the difference between

> There is something to add

and

> There is something to be added

?

It would be great to hear 1) what do both sentences mean to a native speaker and 2) what are the grammar rules behind „to add“ and „to be added“.

I would consider the first example as an active adjectival infinitive and the second one as passive adjectival infinitive.

I often hear „to add“ from native speakers, but I think it should in this case always be „to be added“. This is - to my mind - because „to add“ could be extended to „which is to add“ (indication of future action) and would therefore require action that the object „something“ cannot perform in this case. „Something is added by a person“. Perhaps I‘m just confused…Help for dummies would be appreciated.

Comment: I can't see much scope for different meanings with ***to add*** - but with a different verb, such as ***to do***, there's definitely a difference. ***There's nothing to do*** would usually imply ***I'm bored**!*, whereas ***There's nothing to be done*** is more likely to imply ***My impending doom cannot be prevented**!*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The subtle difference I see is that "to be added" points out that something is missing, whereas "to add" is generally a prologue to doing the adding.

Comment: Thank you aparente001!

Comment: @ExOrbitant - hope it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Both are equally good. I think *to add* is probably more common.

The difference is whether the speaker/writer is focussing on whoever will add the material, or on the material itself. I see no objective difference.

You could regard the first as elliptic for

> There is something for me/you/somebody to add.

without bothering to mention the actor.

Comment: Thank you Colin!

Answer (score 1):

Although in most contexts either phrase is acceptable, in certain circumstances I think “to be added” is more appropriate.

Consider a hypothetical committee meeting drawing up a report to which several people are providing material:

*Situation 1: The chair reads out the report but one of the committee notices that one of the contributions has been forgotten.*

> “There’s something *to add* to the report.”

works best because of brevity, although:

> “There’s something *to be added* to the report.”

would be acceptable.

*Situation 2: The chair reads out the report but one of the committee draws attention to the fact that they still need the contribution from X, who wasn’t able to attend and did not send a paper.*

> “There’s something *to be added* to the report.”

would, I think, be more suitable in this situation as it is clearer that the addition will happen in the not-immediate future.

Comment: Thank you David!